# CLLocationDistance conversion

Tags: iphone

i have distance in a variable of type CLLocationDistance i need to convert it in a integer variable how can i do it

i have use

```
CLLocationDistance kilometers;

int distance = [kilometers intValue];
```

but its giving error.

help guys

Comment: The error that you're receiving may be helpful (to others). Please include it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html

```
distanceFromLocation:
```

**Returns the distance (in meters) from the receiver’s location to the specified location.**

```
- (CLLocationDistance)distanceFromLocation:(const CLLocation *)location
```

**Parameters**

*location* The other location.

**Return Value**
The distance (in meters) between the two locations.

return type is `double` not `int`. And its not an `NSNumber`.

Comment: To clarify, since it's a Double (an intrinsic type, not an object) there is no [intValue] method to run.  Since you're willing to lose accuracy, just assign the value.  If you want to round it, just add .5 and then assign it.

Answer (score 13):

As of iOS 10, there's a new `Measurement` class which makes converting distances a snap.

Here's an extension to convert distances:

```
extension Double {
  func convert(from originalUnit: UnitLength, to convertedUnit: UnitLength) -> Double {
    return Measurement(value: self, unit: originalUnit).converted(to: convertedUnit).value
  }
}
```

Example usage:

```
let miles = 1.0
let metersInAMile = miles.convert(from: .miles, to: .meters)

let mileInFeet = 5280.0
let feetInAMile = mileInFeet.convert(from: .feet, to: .miles)

let marathonInFeet = 138_435.0
let milesInMarathon = marathonInFeet.convert(from: .feet, to: .miles)
let kmInMarathon = marathonInFeet.convert(from: .feet, to: .kilometers)

let inch = 1.0
let centimetersInInch = inch.convert(from: .inches, to: .centimeters)
```

Answer (score 11):

This will calculate the distance between two location by using the `CLLocationDistance`. By default it gives the values in meters. To convert to kilometers, divide the `CLLocationDistance/1000.0`. To get miles multiply the `CLLocationDistance*0.62137`.

```
 //Pass your current location Latitude and longitude
                     CLLocation *currentlocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:13.015370f  longitude:80.200393f];
 //Pass your destination location Latitude and longitude 
CLLocation *destination = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:37.420948f longitude:-122.09578499999998f];
CLLocationDistance meters = [currentlocation distanceFromLocation:destination];
//get distance in meters
    NSLog(@"meters :%f", meters);
//get distance in kilometers
    CLLocationDistance kilometers = meters / 1000.0;
    NSLog(@"kilometers :%f", kilometers);
//Get distance in miles
    NSLog(@"Miles:%f",kilometers*0.62137);
//convert kilometers to int value
    int num=kilometers;
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to improve the answer; code-only answers are discouraged! Thanks!

Comment: This to calculate  distance between two latitude and longitude by using the CLLocationDistance by  default it gives the values in meters. To convert to kilometer divide the CLLocationDistance/1000.0.To get miles multiply the CLLocationDistance*0.62137

Answer (score 7):

**SWIFT 4**

Late to this party, but you can also create an extension like this:

*CLLocationDistance.swift*

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

extension CLLocationDistance {
    func inMiles() -> CLLocationDistance {
        return self*0.00062137
    }

    func inKilometers() -> CLLocationDistance {
        return self/1000
    }
}
```

You could call it as follow:

```
distance.inKilometers()
```

I hope this helps anyone stumbling on this!

Answer (score 4):

**Swift:**

```
  var initialLocation :CLLocation?
  var updatedUserLocation :CLLocation?
  var distanceBetweenLocations: CLLocationDistance?

//MK MapView Delegate
  func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    updatedUserLocation = locations.last
    distanceBetweenLocations =  updatedUserLocation!.distanceFromLocation(initialLocation!)

    //convert To Miles
    distanceBetweenLocations = Utility.convertCLLocationDistanceToMiles(distanceBetweenLocations)

//Setting Distance Value
    distanceLabel.text = String(format: " Distance : %.2f ", distanceBetweenLocations!)

  }
```

**Note :** I have class named Utility which serves the common class methods across the project . This is for better code reusability and reduction.

```
//  Utility.swift

import UIKit
import Foundation
import CoreLocation

class Utility {

  class func convertCLLocationDistanceToMiles (var targetDistance : CLLocationDistance?) -> CLLocationDistance {
    targetDistance =  targetDistance!*0.00062137
    return targetDistance!
  }
  class func convertCLLocationDistanceToKiloMeters (var targetDistance : CLLocationDistance?) -> CLLocationDistance {
    targetDistance =  targetDistance!/1000
    return targetDistance!
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's **so much easier** in Swift:

```
// Use you CLLocationDistance as the value 'kilometers':    
let kms = Measurement(value: kilometers, unit: UnitLength.kilometers)
// Then you can convert that to miles if you'd like:
let miles = kms.converted(to: .miles)
// Get the double value:
let doubleValue = miles.value
print("The distances is \(doubleValue) miles")
```