# how to get the distance between two locations in miles in objective c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mkmapview

how to calculate distance between two location in miles using **distanceFromLocation** method of mapkit framework.

Thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This has already been answered in metric [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905896/distancefromlocation-calculate-distance-between-two-points).  Now you just need to convert meters to miles which is:

```
1 Meter = 0.000621371192 Miles
```

or

```
1 Mile = 1609.344 Meters
```

Answer (score 26):

Try below code:

```
double latA = [currentlat floatValue];
double logA = [currentlong floatValue];

double latB = [toLat floatValue];
double logB = [toLong floatValue];

CLLocation *locA = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:latA
                                              longitude:logA];

CLLocation *locB = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:latB longitude:logB];
CLLocationDistance distance = [locA distanceFromLocation:locB];
NSLog(@"Calculated Miles %@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1fmi",(distance/1609.344)]);
```

Answer (score 3):

The function seems fairly self explanatory in Apple's documentation? It will give the distance between the user's location and the location given, so you'd have to create a new CLLocation object to tell the iPhone where you want to go.

The function gives the result in meters. To convert to miles, multiply by 0.000621371192. More information is given in [this thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888200/cllocationdistance-conversion)