# Display the distance from user with mapKit Swift (miles/km)

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationdistance

I have been attempting to display the distance on a tableView but I am unable to get it to happen. This question follows up from this question: [CLLocationDistance conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888200/cllocationdistance-conversion). I have checked the distance. Using this function in my `Location` class:

```
// Get distance
func distance(to location: CLLocation) -> CLLocationDistance {
    return location.distance(from: self.location)
}
```

How I get the users current location:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let location = locations[0]

    let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01)
    let myLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)
    let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(myLocation, span)
    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    // Add a lastUserLocation to LocationManager and update it every time that the delegate receives a new location
    LocationManager.shared.lastUserLocation = locations.last
    LocationManager.shared.sortLocationsInPlace()

    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true

}
```

Sort function in LocationManager:

```
func getSortedLocations(userLocation: CLLocation) -> [Location] {
        return locations.sorted { (l1, l2) -> Bool in
            return l1.distance(to: userLocation) < l2.distance(to: userLocation)
        }
    }

func sortLocationsInPlace() {
    if let validLocation = lastUserLocation {
        locations.sort { (l1, l2) -> Bool in
            return l1.distance(to: validLocation) < l2.distance(to: validLocation)
        } 
    }
}
```

cellForRowAt:

```
var sortedLocations = [Location]()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "locationCell", for: indexPath)


    let location = sortedLocations[indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel?.text = location.name
    return cell
}
```

**Update**

Inside `Location` class:

```
class Location {

    var name: String
    var latitude: Double
    var longitude: Double
    var location:CLLocation {
        return CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
    }

    init?(json: JSON) {

        guard let name = json["name"] as? String, let latitude = json["latitude"] as? Double, let longitude = json["longitude"] as? Double else { return nil }
        self.name = name
        self.latitude = latitude
        self.longitude = longitude
    }

    func distance(to location: CLLocation) -> CLLocationDistance {
        return location.distance(from: self.location)
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question does not provide enough information. What are the entries in the array that you display in a table view? CLLocation locations of different objects? Are you supposed to be calculating the distance between an array of locations and the user's current location? How is your function `distance()` being called? Please edit your question to provide information about the above.

Comment: what do you have in `LocationManager.shared.location`? it seems to me that you are using it instead of `lastUserLocation` to do your comparisons

Comment: @JavierMedina Please see my updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering your code, I am making some assumptions:

1. Your `sortedLocations` array has different locations that you extracted from a *JSON* or whatever.
2. You call [startUpdatingLocation()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423750-startupdatinglocation) or similar somewhere before loading your data.
3. You are **receiving updates** in your `didUpdateLocations`.
4. Your `LocationManager` keeps an ordered copy of all your locations in a variable called `locations`, the one you are ordering inside `didUpdateLocations`.

**That considered**, what I understand you want to do is to display your `sortedLocations` ordered according to a *reference location*.

What is missing is to update your `UITableView` data once your user location is received. You have two main options:

1. To only load your `UITableView` once you have already your first user location retrieved by `didUpdateLocations`.
2. To force a `UITableView` update once you get a new location, by calling `tableView.reloadData()` inside `didUpdateLocations`. This will redraw your list every time you receive a location update, sorting them by location.

**However**, in any of those cases you need to replace your `cellForRow` text to display your distance instead of `location.name`:

```
// Distance in meters
cell.textLabel?.text = String(location.distance(to: LocationManager.shared.lastUserLocation!))

// Distance in miles
cell.textLabel?.text = String(location.distance(to: LocationManager.shared.lastUserLocation!)*0.00062137)
```

And **update** your `didUpdateLocations`:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    if let location = locations.last {

        let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01)
        let myLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)
        let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(myLocation, span)
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

        // Add a lastUserLocation to LocationManager and update it every time that the delegate receives a new location
        LocationManager.shared.lastUserLocation = location
        LocationManager.shared.sortLocationsInPlace()

        sortedLocations = LocationManager.shared.locations
        tableView.reloadData()

        self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true
    }
}
```

With your current code you are comparing all distances with a `self.location` variable that its not being initialised anywhere apparently.

Comment: I am aiming to force the the UITableView to update once you get a new location so it is constantly updating.

Comment: then calling reloadData and fixing your distance functions should be enough

Comment: I have tried that and also defined it as `var lastUserLocation: CLLocation?` but `self.lastUserLocation` is nil

Comment: if you put a breakpoint inside `didUpdateLocations`, is it called at any time?

Comment: It does, but when I print out: `LocationManager.shared.lastUserLocation = locations.last` I get nil

Comment: I did that before where you made a func with `sortedLocations = LocationManager.shared.locations` and
    `tableView.reloadData()` and called it at the bottom of locationManager, but still getting a nil

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156835/discussion-between-jvrmed-and-mninety5).

Comment: @mninety5 please remember to accept the answer if it was helpful ;)

Comment: I know this is a bit delayed but how would I achieve the other option which you suggested which is _"To only load your UITableView once you have already your first user location retrieved by didUpdateLocations"_. I'd like it to be sorted once they press a button, and only sort once. I currently can perform the `sortedLocations = LocationManager.shared.locations` and `reloadData()` at the button action but then the tableView is empty until this action performs.

Comment: either by using a delegate or subscribing your table to a notification, user NotificationCenter